# Cannot log into chat

Tags: support, chat

I am unable to log into chat.stackexhange.com (linked from serverfault.com). I have read other posts here about this but this has not solved the problem.

I have logged out of all SE sites, destroyed global credentials, cleared browser (Firefox 3.6.13) cache, confirmed that localStorage is enabled and restarted the browser. Cookies and scripts from all stackexchange-related sites are permitted. I have enough reputation points at ServerFault to participate in chat. I am still unable to login. The GlobalAuth tester reports that localStorage is not enabled. Suggestions please.

Comment: You say that you confirmed localStorage is enabled, but that the test page reports it isn't.  How did you confirm it is enabled?  As you restarted the browser, can you confirm it is still enabled?

Comment: I confirmed by navigating to about:config and looking at value dom.localstorage.enabled, which is set to true.

Comment: Maybe that's the culprit -- The correct key in about:config would be `dom.storage.enabled`. Could you double check that?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that dom.storage.enabled is true; I simply typed it incorrectly in my comment above. The key I typed above does not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the case that the automatic login fails (for whatever reason), you can use the alternate login at https://stackexchange.com/users/chat-login. If you're not logged in to stackexchange.com yet, you will automatically be redirected to the regular OpenID login page.

This secondary login link is also displayed in the "not able to automatically log in" message:

[image: notification on chat asking to log in]

and on the [chat login page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global):

[image: "log in via Stack Exchange" link on the chat login page]

Comment: Thanks. I saw the explanation at the bottom of the page, but hadn't tried it yet. It works! I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer, but I've accepted it.

Comment: Non of this is working for me. I can login to the other sites chat rooms but not askdifferent/stackexchange. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> The GlobalAuth tester reports that localStorage is not enabled

Your browser is misconfigured from the default. Try a different web browser, or run Firefox in safe mode.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble has to do with cookies -- believe it or not. I just solved it for me. Deal is: If your browser is configured to ask you for every cookie to accept it, localStorage fails (see [Firefox Failing localStorage Due to Cookie Policy](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2012/04/25/firefox-failing-localstorage/). My work-around is mentioned in the comments: With Firefox, using an addon like [Cookie Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-button/?src=ss), I made sure to accept cookies from all involved SE sites (including stackauth.com). Et voila! Login worked.